ApexChart timeline distributed legend
I have an ApexChart timeline, setted as distributed, but the legend doesn't want to follow the distribution. How can I set the chart to show the legend for the bars?
chartOptions = {
            series: [{
                data: chartData
            }],
            title: {
                text: data.title,
                align: 'left'
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'rangeBar'
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                show: true,
                showForSingleSeries: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    distributed: true,
                    horizontal: true 
                }
            }
        };


I created a custom legend from data, but I hope, there is a more elegant solution.
